# Stop WGET from returning 'shortlink' Wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, wget, gnu

I'm using `WGET` to scrape two *almost* identical sites.

Then I plan on running a `DIFF` to find any differences. (I'm moving a site to a new server basically and want to make sure all is up to scratch)

Here are my results from my scraping on the old and on the new server:

[image]

You can see below that there are many `index.html?p=?` files on the new server.

I have managed to work out that it's due to a tag in the code linking to a 'shortlink' version of the page. This is pulled in through a plugin called 'Yoast' which exists on the new server but not the old. Other than that, the site is almost exactly identical. (Even server settings etc)

(There are over 2,000 of those index files in the directory)

[image]

I need the results of each `WGET` to be the same so that I can `DIFF` the two sites.

This is the tag in the code causing this to happen on the new server:

[image]

Now for the main question. How can I make `WGET` ignore these shortlink tags and scrape the site as it would on the old server?

I have tried all sorts of different `WGET` parameters but nothing has worked yet. This is my current `WGET` command:

```
wget --recursive --html-extension --page-requisites --convert-links www.domain.ac.uk
```

How can I modify this command to ignore 'shortlink' tags?

Thank you

---

I've found out how to remove the actual tag. It's not a fix for me because I need the tag there but for others who come across this, add this to your functions.php:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Comment: You can remove the tag itself with: `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't work it out but if you are also the owner of the website you're scanning you can simply add:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

To your functions.php to hide the meta tag.